# Desktop Environment Screen Goes Black when Screen is Static

Tags: debian, drivers, desktop-environment

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 2-in-1 with a i5-1035g1, 8gb ddr4 ram, and integrated graphics. I have only tested Debian distros, but I have tested a number of different desktop environments, but all of them have the same issue. If nothing is happening (no pixels are changing) on my screen it immediately goes black until I move the mouse or do something to make a pixel change (typing, moving mouse, pressing play to a video, etc). This does not happen if a video is playing. Also I would like to add that I installed kali wsl-2 with win-kex and the desktop environment for that does not have this issue.

I have looked at many other posts on similar issues, but haven't found anything to work. I think it might be a driver issue, but I cant seem to figure out what driver I would want, or if there even is an incorrect driver.

If you want more details on my laptop, here is a link to the amazon page for this device. [https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-5000-Touchscreen-i5-1035G1/dp/B08PTW4QD2/ref=dp_fod_2?pd_rd_i=B08PTW4QD2&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08PTW4QD2)

On my current distro (kali) here is what `sudo lspci` displays

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Solution (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 0001
```

Comment: Could you please clarify "*If nothing is happening (no pixels are changing) on my screen it immediately goes black*"? **How many seconds/minutes do you have between leaving your computer untouched and the black screen?** (This duration could be related to **power management**, check [the documentation on gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/power.html.en#saving))

Comment: It turns completely black less than a second after everything stops moving. My settings are all normal and it shouldn't go black until 4 minutes. Does that clarify it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for these details. I can't help you more though